# Supabase database function using foreign keys

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I am using supabase for the first time and I am facing a problem on the signup process.

I use a database function, using the model from the SQL editor quick start. Here is the function I use, triggered on *on_auth_user_created* :

```
begin
  insert into public.profiles (id, full_name, team)
  values (new.id, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'full_name', new.raw_user_meta_data->>'team');
  return new;
end;
```

This is the database structure :

Table **teams** :

- *id* : int8
- *name* : text

Table **profiles** :

- *id* : uuid references auth.user.id
- *team* : int8 references public.teams.id
- *full_name* : text

Now, here is the problem, when using only *id* and *full_name* on the database function, it work, but when I had team I get **AuthApiError: Database error saving new user**.

I find nothing on the web and I have no idea why I can't make it work.

Comment: Check your postgres logs to see what the error was, I'm going to guess the team id that you've entered doesn't exist in the teams table hence why the record can't save.

Comment: I am glad I'm not the only one. I also got this error when trying to insert to a column that's a foreign key using `raw_user_meta_data`. But it won't if I use a hardcoded string. Most likely a bug from Supabase.